# how to add property to each of the objects based on temp value ,but don't change the order of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, properties, javascript-objects

I am working with a array of objects and i need to add property 'orderTemp' to each of the objects based on temp value where i don't need to change the order of objects

My initial array of objects looks like so

```
[
  { humidity: 95, location: 'Konstanz', pressure: 1003, temp: 22.46 },
  { humidity: 45, location: 'India', pressure: 1014, temp: 2.23 },
   ...
];
```

So my resulting array of objects would look something like so

```
[
  { humidity: 95, location: 'Konstanz', pressure: 1003, temp: 22.46, orderTemp: 2 },
  { humidity: 45, location: 'India', pressure: 1014, temp: 2.23, orderTemp: 1 },
   ...
];
```

Comment: where are you getting stuck? Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: i'm looking for a better solution because i think my solution is bad, i have tried first sorting the data and then add index with findIndex,  something like this {...item, orderTemp: [...data].sort((a, b) => a.temp - b.temp).findIndex(x => x.name === item.name) + 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
// get list of all temperature values and sort it
const temperatures = data.map(item => item.temp).sort();

// if you want to change source data
data.forEach(item => item.orderTemp = temperatures.indexOf(item.temp));

// if you want create new array with this additional field in object
const newData = data.map(item => ({ 
    ...item,
    orderTemp: temperatures.indexOf(item.temp)
  })
);
```